# Handling null objects in custom JsonConverter's ReadJson method

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got a Newtonsoft JSON.NET `JsonConverter` to help deserialize a property whose type is an abstract class. The gist of it looks like this:

```
public class PetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Animal);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (jsonObject["Lives"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<Cat>(serializer);
        if (jsonObject["StopPhrase"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<Parrot>(serializer);

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Here are the classes it handles:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{ }

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public int Lives { get; set; }
}

public class Parrot : Animal
{
    public string StopPhrase { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PetConverter))]
    public Animal Pet { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine when deserializing a `Person` that has a non-null `Pet`. But if the `Pet` is null, then the `ReadJson` method breaks on the first line with this a `JsonReaderException`:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Null. Path 'Pet', line 1, position 11.

I've checked [the Custom JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) documentation, but it is merely about a *writing* converter. I've tried the following:

```
if (reader.Value == null) return null; // this inverts the [Test] results
```

But then I get:

> JsonSerializationException: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.

For cases when the property *is* populated.

In short, what is the proper way to handle this situation?

---

For completeness, here are some unit tests that demonstrate the issue at hand:

```
[TestFixture]
public class JsonConverterTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Cat_survives_serialization_roundtrip()
    {
        var person = new Person { Pet = new Cat { Lives = 9 } };
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(serialized);
        Assert.That(deserialized.Pet, Is.InstanceOf<Cat>());
        Assert.That((deserialized.Pet as Cat).Lives, Is.EqualTo(9));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Parrot_survives_serialization_roundtrip()
    {
        var person = new Person { Pet = new Parrot { StopPhrase = "Lorrie!" } };
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(serialized);
        Assert.That(deserialized.Pet, Is.InstanceOf<Parrot>());
        Assert.That((deserialized.Pet as Parrot).StopPhrase, Is.EqualTo("Lorrie!"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void Null_property_does_not_break_converter()
    {
        var person = new Person { Pet = null };
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(serialized);
        Assert.That(deserialized.Pet, Is.Null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

While writing the question, specifically while writing the "what have I tried" bit, I find one possible solution:

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;
```

I'm posting this for two reasons:

1. If it's good enough, it might help someone else with the same question.
2. I might learn of a better, competing solution from someone else's answer.

FWIW, here's the full JsonConverter for very basic handling deserialization of a property whose type is an abstract class:

```
public class PetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Animal);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;

        JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (jsonObject["Lives"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<Cat>(serializer);
        if (jsonObject["StopPhrase"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<Parrot>(serializer);

        return null;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And/or you could load your JSON as a `JToken` and check for `token.Type == JTokenType.Null`.  Though actually your solution seems best.

Comment: In my case, the `reader` didn't has the correct state when returning null. Therefore, I came up with a combination of the answer's solution and the suggestion of [dbc]: `if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) { JToken.Load(reader); return null; }`.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, just writing to say your suggestion helped fix my problem, though to be totally honest, I have no idea why. My initial code had something similar to yours, where in the ReadJson I tried simply saying "if (reader.Value is Animal)", however, reader.Value was always null (despite it actually having a value). In the end I just went with your idea, and used "jsonObject[MyValue] != null" as you did with Lives/StopPhrase.

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy Glad to hear my Q&A was helpful to you!

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy I had the same confusion as you, although now I understand that `reader.Value` is `null` despite it actually having a value because the initial token is a `JsonToken.StartObject`, e.g. literally a `{` (which doesn't have a value)!